# Blocked referral - How many times it was referred

Tags: .htaccess

I have blocked some domain referrals to my site in .htaccess like below

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example2\.com [NC]
```

Is it possible for me to check how many times url requests were made to via this referral?

I checked my log files & did not find any. So.. I assume they are blocked and log file will not make a record of it.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `[F]` flag no script is being executed. Apache sends the header, and does not do anything else.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

These requests are still logged in your access log, just like any other request. I believe the requested resource, as well as the referer header are displayed in this log, so you might be able to automatically process this file to find the lines that contain a certain string.

---

If you want to log specific information that is not in the access log you need to approach this differently. Rewrite each request to a file, but do not use the `[F]` flag. Instead, send the appropriate header in php and do the logging in the file you rewrite to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example1\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example2\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/log\.php
RewriteRule ^ log.php [L]
```

With log.php

```
<?php
$f = fopen( "log.txt", "a" );
fwrite( $f, time() . "\n" );

header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
```